# Java Restful Webservice returns 404 Not Found (Intellij Ultimate Edition)

Tags: java, api, rest, web-services, jax-rs

I'm trying to create RESTful webservices with JAX RS library in Intellij Ultimate Edition.

I've create Webservice Project and added Maven framework to the project.

Below is the web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1" metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>restapijava</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Service1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.restful.java.example</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Service1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.restful.java.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>restapijava</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Java class is:

```
package com.restful.java.example;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/poc")
public class Sample {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayHelloInXML() {
        String name = "Tom";
        System.out.println("POC: Sending XML response to name : "+name);
        return name;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/jsonview")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JsonObject sayHelloInJSON() {
        String name = "Tom";
        JsonObject jsonObj = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("name", name)
                .add("service", "POC")
                .build();
        return jsonObj;
    }
}
```

When I try to hit URL : http://localhost:8080/restapijava/api/poc It gives 404 Not Found error. Any help is appreciated !!

Comment: It should be `@Path` not `@ApplicationPath`

Comment: @PaulSamsotha It's giving same 404 Not Found error with Path too.

Comment: add `@Path("/")` to your `sayHelloInXML()` method